# acces static class properties from aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I am on .aspx page and i want to take the width and height of a control from a static class
where i have defined them as constans.

Is there any way to access that class directly from the aspx page?

I know that i can make a method like:

```
width="<%= getWidthSize() %>"
```

and inside the aspx.cs to define this method to take the size from that static class.

But i am asking if this could be directly managed from the web aspx page...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they're in the same namespace, you can simply use

```
<%= ClassName.StaticMethod() %>
```

If the method you want to call is in another namespace, you need to either specify the full path

```
<%= Namespace.ClassName.StaticMethod() %>
```

or add an import page directive

```
<%@ Import namespace=”Namespace” %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add an import directive and reference the static class propery directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx

E.g.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="SomeNamespace" %>

<%=SomeClass.SomeProperty.ToString() %>
```